# From express + pg to reusable code : help refactoring

Tags: node.js, express, refactoring, node-postgres

So, I have some node code to deal with and I’m hoping someone here can help me refactor it. This is express + pg:

```
app.get('/path', function (req, res, next) {
  pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, releaseClientToPool) {
    client.query(query, function(err, data) {
      if(err) {
        res.send(tellFrontEndThereIsAnError);
      } else {
        res.send(tellFrontEndYay);
      }
         releaseClientToPool); 
    });
  }); 
});
```

I want to extract the part that runs the query, that is, basically everything inside the express controller action. Except of course, nested inside the callbacks, is express code. How would you refactor this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use knex.js for query building  http://knexjs.org/

controller:

```
var foo = require('foo');

app.get('/path', function (req, res, next) {
    foo.bar(function(err, result) {
        if(err) res.send('send error to front end');
        else res.send('send your result here to front end');
    });
}
```

module: `foo.js`

```
var knex = require('knex')(dbConfig)
module.exports = {
    bar: function(callback) {
        knex.select('*')
        .from('table')
        .then(function(result) {
            callback(null, result)
        })
        .catch(callback);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An example with the help of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise):

```
var pgp = require('pg-promise')(/*options*/);
var db = pgp('postgres://username:password@host:port/database');

app.get('/path', function (req, res, next) {
    db.query("SELECT * FROM table")
        .then(data=> {
            // set response with the data;
        })
        .catch(error=> {
            // set response with the error;
        });
});
```

How you want to module such code is up to you.